# Basecamp BCX API Internal Error when posting comment to Basecamp Classic

Tags: basecamp

I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to post a comment to an existing post on Basecamp Classic.  Any help in resolving how to fix this is appreciated.

In general, is it possible to interact with Basecamp Classic using the new API?  I haven't really seen any documentation on this, it would be helpful if someone could point it out.

```
     $.ajax({
       url: _accountHref + '/projects/' + $projectId + '/posts/' + $postId + '/comments.json',
       headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _token,
         'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
       },  
       data: { 'content' : "I'm alive!" },  
       type: 'POST',
       //type: 'PUT',
       success: function(data, status) {
       }   
     });
```

Below are the request headers if that is helpful (with tokens and session ids stripped out)

```
POST /projects/12737365/posts/91927305/comments.json HTTP/1.1
Host: anideninteractive.basecamphq.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 18
Authorization: Bearer <auth-token>
Origin: https://anideninteractive.basecamphq.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
DNT: 1
Referer: https://anideninteractive.basecamphq.com/projects/12737365-graphic-plan-aniden-test/log
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ca;q=0.6
Cookie: twisted_token=<twisted-token>;
session_token=<session-token>; return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fanideninteractive.basecamphq.com%2Fprojects%2F12737365-graphic-plan-aniden-test%2Flog; flashVersion=Shockwave%20Flash%2017.0%20r0; _basecamp_session_v2=<basecamp-session-v2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I sent this question to support at Basecamp.  They said you can not access Basecamp Classic via the new API.